# SwiftUI & CoreData - ordered list

Tags: ios, swift, list, core-data, swiftui

**I am trying to make an ordered list in SwiftUI using CoreData records.
How to print running numbers in such list?**

In the following example I have one entity named **SomeEntity** with a String attribute named **title**.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

   var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<SomeEntity>
   var items: FetchedResults<SomeEntity> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List {

            ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in

            NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailsView(item: item)) {

                HStack {
                    Text("99")
                    // How to print running number instead of "99" in this ordered list of CoreData records?
                    // I was thinking about something like this:
                    // Text(items.id) - but this doesn't work. Is there something similar?
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(width: 60)
                    Text(item.title!)
               }
           }
           }


         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "running numbers"? Is it "ordinal number"?

Comment: `Text("\(item.id)")` maybe?

Comment: Yes, just 1.itemName, 2.itemName, 3.itemName. Reversed order would be even better: 3,2,1. I was thinking that I could get index from every instance of Entity. Or using a count and -1 for every next instance. But I cannot find a working example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need something like the following

```
struct ContentView: View {

   var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<SomeEntity>
   var items: FetchedResults<SomeEntity> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List {

            ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.element) {(i, item) in

            NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailsView(item: item)) {

                HStack {
                    Text("\(i + 1)")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(width: 60)
                    Text(item.title!)
               }
           }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It works great for growing numbers. I will check second answer from iSpain17 to get reversed order.

Comment: For reversed just use `enumerated().reversed()`

Comment: it works but breaks .fetchBatchSize = 10 requests so take that into account

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, this should work: You need to use a different `init` of `ForEach`, which takes a `Range<Int>` as first argument:

```
ForEach(-items.count..<0, id: \.self) { i in 
    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailsView(item: items[-i])) {
        HStack {
            Text("\(items[-i].itemName)")
                .multiLineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: 60)
            Text("\(items[-i].title!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Going from `-items.count` to `0` also ensures the reversed order.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, iSpain17. I had few problems with your code - maybe I made some mistake and didn't implement it correct. But Asperi's answer solved the problem already.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it and with @FetchRequest this solution seems to be the best.

```
 List {

        ForEach(self.contacts.indices, id: \.self) { i in


            Button(action: {
                self.selectedId = self.contacts[i].id!
            }) {

                ContactRow(contact: self.contacts[i])
                    .equatable()
                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.01))
            }
            .buttonStyle(ListButtonStyle())
            .frame(height: 64)  
            .listRowBackground( (i%2 == 0) ? Color("DarkRowBackground") : .white)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
```

I've tested also solution with Array(self.contacts.enumerated()) but it doesn't work as well. If you there is small number of records it can be ok but for large number of records it is suboptimal.

If you use

```
request.fetchBatchSize = 10
```

to load records (entities) in batches while scrolling the list enumerated() doesn't work executes all needed SELECT ... LIMIT 10 requests at once

.indices makes it possible to fetch additional items while scrolling.